# Oracle error: Not a group by function

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    Select EVENTPLAN.PLANNO, EVENTPLANLINE.LINENO, RESOURCETBL.RESNAME,
    COUNT(EVENTPLANLINE.NUMBERFLD) AS NUMBEROFRESOURCES,
    LOCATION.LOCNAME, EVENTPLANLINE.TIMESTART, EVENTPLANLINE.TIMEEND
    FROM  EVENTPLAN, RESOURCETBL, EVENTPLANLINE, LOCATION, FACILITY
    WHERE EVENTPLAN.PLANNO = EVENTPLANLINE.PLANNO
    AND   EVENTPLANLINE.RESNO = RESOURCETBL.RESNO
    AND   EVENTPLANLINE.LOCNO = LOCATION.LOCNO
    AND   FACILITY.FACNO = LOCATION.FACNO
    AND   FACILITY.FACNAME = 'Basketball arena'
    AND   EVENTPLAN.ACTIVITY = 'Operation'
    AND   EVENTPLAN.WORKDATE BETWEEN '1-OCT-13' AND '31-DEC-13'
    GROUP BY EVENTPLAN.PLANNO, EVENTPLANLINE.LINENO,                           
    RESOURCETBL.RESNAME,EVENTPLANLINE.NUMBERFLD;
```

On running this query I am getting an error: Not a group by function. Can someone please tell me why am I getting this error? I have added all the fields in the GROUP BY function.

Comment: You should learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an aggregate function ALL scalar fields must be in `GROUP BY` function.

You have missed these:

```
LOCATION.LOCNAME, EVENTPLANLINE.TIMESTART, EVENTPLANLINE.TIMEEND
```

So, the right query will be:

```
SELECT
    EVENTPLAN.PLANNO, EVENTPLANLINE.LINENO, RESOURCETBL.RESNAME,
    COUNT(EVENTPLANLINE.NUMBERFLD) AS NUMBEROFRESOURCES,
    LOCATION.LOCNAME, EVENTPLANLINE.TIMESTART, EVENTPLANLINE.TIMEEND
FROM  EVENTPLAN, RESOURCETBL, EVENTPLANLINE, LOCATION, FACILITY
WHERE EVENTPLAN.PLANNO = EVENTPLANLINE.PLANNO
AND   EVENTPLANLINE.RESNO = RESOURCETBL.RESNO
AND   EVENTPLANLINE.LOCNO = LOCATION.LOCNO
AND   FACILITY.FACNO = LOCATION.FACNO
AND   FACILITY.FACNAME = 'Basketball arena'
AND   EVENTPLAN.ACTIVITY = 'Operation'
AND   EVENTPLAN.WORKDATE BETWEEN '1-OCT-13' AND '31-DEC-13'
GROUP BY EVENTPLAN.PLANNO, EVENTPLANLINE.LINENO, RESOURCETBL.RESNAME,
LOCATION.LOCNAME, EVENTPLANLINE.TIMESTART, EVENTPLANLINE.TIMEEND
```

Comment: oh now I know what i was missing !

Comment: @MaryamMasood: Have a nice day ;)